# Permissions for shared folder in windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows

```
We have Windows Server 2008 R2 as Workgroup installed. We have shared 1 folder
```

. When we login with administrator we are not able to delete or save file.

When i try to copy folder to another location as backup even then it is not copying complete folder . It gives message "Access Denied"

Thanks

Comment: What are the security permissions on that shared folder?  From the server, right-click on the shared folder and choose properties.  Then go to the security tab.  You should see a list of "Users" then below that a list of "Permissions"  For the Administrator account, tell me what permissions are checked "Allow" & "Deny."  If the administrator account is the server administrator account, "Full Control" should be checked allow, but that doesn't keep somebody from changing it.  "When we login with administrator......" says to me that too many people know the administrator account.

Comment: You may need to change the filesystem permissions in addition to the SMB share permissions for the specific user, although admin should already have FS access.

Comment: Hi , Administrator has full control . Secondly standard user is able to change permission when user right click & select properties  which we don't want to allow.

Comment: Hi , problem i am facing is when i give special permissions to a user & unclick Delete in "Allow" user is not able to delete but he is also not able to save file after making changes . When i allow Delete then user is able to make changes but he is also able to delete file which i don't want.